# Ng-include not populating div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

On my webpage I have multiple instances where the same table will be shown. So instead of having the table hard coded in every time I'm using ng-include from AngularJS. But for some reason once I place the table inside its own html page and put an ng-include in its place it just doesn't appear on the page at all. The only clue i get is in the console log it has an error stating "angular.js:9827 GET http://localhost:58893/Dashboards/project-information.html 404 (Not Found)"

index.cshtml

```
<div class="ibox-content" id="ibox-2"><!--DIV CONTENT-->
    <div class="active content table-responsive" ng-include="'project-information.html'"></div>
</div>
```

project-information.html

```
<table class="table selectOption">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Project </th>
        <th>Name </th>
        <th>Phone </th>
        <th>Company </th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <!--Angular; Repeats all of the content in the dTIMS project array-->
    <tr class="option" ng-repeat="product in projectCtrl.products">
        <td>{{  product.id  }}</td>
        <td>{{  product.name  }}</td>
        <td>{{  product.supervisor  }}</td>
        <td>{{  product.phone  }}</td>
        <td>{{  product.company  }}</td>
        <td>{{  product.date  }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

app.js

```
app.controller('ProjectController', function () {
    this.products = projects
});
```

header.cshtml

```
<html ng-app="dTIMSApp">
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="ProjectController as projectCtrl">
        ....call to the index page inside here
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: seems like a file path issue, can you share your template file path?

Comment: The error just says the file `http://localhost:58893/Dashboards/project-information.html` is not found. Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: @user2954587 I'm confused doesn't the ng-include connect to the page it references?

Comment: @Markus yes, is the full file path to `project-information.html` /Dashboards/project-information.html ?

Comment: @user2954587 yes it is, it originally wasnt in the Dashboards folder so i moved it there and still same error. I'm going to try and put a picture up of the tree to show everyone what the path looks like

Comment: maybe try `../Views/Dashboards/project-information.html` ? sometimes you also need to add quotes to your file paths, for example `ng-include="'Dashboards/project-information.html'"`

Comment: @user2954587 yeah i actually tried that for about an hour but it didn't change anything

Comment: @Joy yeah i had a feeling it had something to do with the path but i tried every version of the path i could think of but no change. I added a picture of the tree so you can check the path for yourself

Comment: the "Views" doesn't make part of path? How will you do if you need to access any view directly?

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo so what would the path look like then, because I've tried "'/Views/Dashboards/project-information.html'" along with every variation, and still same error

Comment: Try to create at "Scripts" a folder "includes" and put the html into. I believe your server doesn't allow to access directly the Views folder.

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo That fixed it! I made a includes folder inside the Scripts folder and changed the ng-include path too "'/Scripts/includes/project-information.html'". The only issue i have now is that my javascript i had for the table doesnt work (highlights the tr when clicked). Either way if you put up an answer i will mark it as the answer.

Comment: I will create an issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some servers doesn't allow to access views folder.

Create a folder "includes" on your existing Scripts folder, and put html into.

On ng-include, use the new path:

```
<div 
    class="active content table-responsive" 
    ng-include="'/Scripts/includes/project-information.html'">
</div>
```